# Python Fail to assign a value to an empty cell in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe `example`:

```
|  A  |  B  |
|:----|:----|
|  1  |  LA |
|  2  |None |
|NaN  |  TX |
```

I only want to fill the null values for the last row with the max value of the column.

```
example.iloc[-1]['A'] = example['A'].max()
```

The code above does not change the NaN value.

Comment: This fails with a `SettingWithCopyWarning` because `example.iloc[-1]` then `['A']` is a slice of a slice, which makes a copy. Instead, you want to index all in one `.iloc[]`/`.loc[]` expression, not multiple chained slices.

Comment: @smci Gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: That's a really good explanation.

Comment: Admittedly it's an annoying pandas limitation that you can't mix `.iloc[]` numbered indexing (e.g. of rows) with `.loc[]` named indexing (of columns). So you just have to use `.iloc[]` numbered indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you expect?

```
>>> df['A'].fillna(df['A'].max())
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

With your code, you have probably a `SettingWithCopyWarning` message?

You can use also:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = df['A'].max()
print(df)

     A     B
0  1.0    LA
1  2.0  None
2  2.0    TX
```

Comment: Yes, I did get the warning. The second one works better for my situation! I need to modify each cell in the last row with the same logic. Thanks a lot!